# Gradle Error URI has an authority component

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to install gradle .when i try to execute 
`gradle -v` command.

I get the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.findDistDir(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

OS - `Windows 7`
Java JDK version  - `1.7`
Gradle version - `2.5`

can some one tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

`java -version` command works fine in the command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI has an authority component: As the error suggests the gradle path whichever you have used contain some special characters like //. Which makes it unusable.